# OIDC SignOut AuthenticationProperties Parameters not reflected on IdentityServer sign-out Context

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an IdentityServer4 server running in ASP.Net Core 3.1 (using scaffolded ASP.Net Core Identity) and authenticating users of my separate ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web Application.

My problem is at Sign-Out, in which the IdentiyServer signout context is not reflecting parameters that are defined on the client side.

Here's the setup:
The Client's Logout Controller Method ends like so:

```
var ap = new AuthenticationProperties();
ap.Parameters.Add("Reason", reason);
ap.Parameters.Add("TenantId", profileId.ToString());
return SignOut(ap, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

I have a custom OpenIdConnectEvents Class defined like so:

```
public class CustomOpenIdConnectEvents : OpenIdConnectEvents
{
  public override async Task RedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(RedirectContext context)
  {
    await base.RedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(context);
    //a breakpoint on the above line confirms that the context.Properties.Parameters contains the values defined in the Controller logout method
  }
}
```

hooked up as follows in the `Startup.cs` of the Client:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    //irrelevant cookie options here
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomOpenIdConnectEvents);
    //other option settings here
});
```

On the IdentityServer, the Logout Page is called, and the `OnGet()` method looks like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    var context = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
    //at this point I expect context.Parameters to reflect the parameters sent from the client, but the .Parameters is empty.

    //other code
}
```

Why are the Parameters defined on the OIDC Client side not being passed to the OIDC Server?  What am I missing? (btw, on the Client I have also tried populating the `.Items` property instead of the `.Parameters` property but it made no difference)

Comment: I'm clearly missing something fundamental in my approach, as I've managed to replicate the problem on the IdentityServer4 QuickStart 2.  Will do further investigation and revert.

Comment: I got it!! Solution added as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The logout method should never return anything, because the signout method themself do create their own response.

So it should look something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Do the logout
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        //Important, this method should never return anything.
    }
```

Perhaps you need to set the LogoutPath as well? its a security feature as the slide from my training class show:

[image]

Logout path is set on the Addcookie handler.

```
.AddCookie(options =>
  {
      options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
      options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied";
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how the SignOut from the client *should* be done.  Sadly though, it does nothing to solve the problem I asked about.  The Parameters I'm specifying at SignOut on the client are still not passed to the Identity Server's SignOut mechanism.

Comment: Thanks.  But my problem isn't that the SignOut page on the Identity Server isn't being called.  The redirects are all happening as expected.  My problem is that the context in the IdentityServer's signout page is not reflecting the parameters that I am sending from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!

In my `CustomOpenIdConnectEvents` class, I had to add the Parameters to the `context.ProtocolMessage`, like so:

```
public override Task RedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(RedirectContext context)
{
  foreach (var item in context.Properties.Parameters)
    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
  return base.RedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(context);
}
```